# Regular expression to extract title from web page

Tags: c#, regex

I have the code below that calls the website and extract title from the page. Working fine but it also extract new line characters or tab. so sometimes the string looks like

`\r\n\tSome WebSite | Official Company Website\r\n`

```
public string GetPageTitle(string url)
    {
        string regex = @"(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)";
        string source = this._client.DownloadString(url);
        return Regex.Match(source, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;           
    }
```

what should be the regular expression to ignore `\r\n` and `\t`

Comment: Use `String.Trim()`. Add `.Trim();` to `.Value`.

Comment: Could try class subtraction https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994330.aspx like `[\S\s-[\r\n\t]]`

Comment: If you want to integrate it into your regex, could try this `@"(?<=<title.*>)\s*([\S\s-[\r\n\t]]*)\s*(?=</title>)"` but this will restrict the capture to only non-linebreak, continuous text. So you could miss some with internal breaks. The other option is to trim inside the regex `\s*([\S\s]*?)\s*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consider Non-Regular Expression Options**

If you aren't set explicitly on a Regular Expression, it's worth noting that the [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) method will remove any leading and trailing white-space from your string, which includes tabs and new lines :

```
return Regex.Match(source, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value.Trim();
```

Likewise an explicit replacement would work as well :

```
return Regex.Match(source, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value
                                                          .Replace("\t","")
                                                          .Replace(Environment.NewLine,"");
```